# asp.net Problem with assembly reference

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, reference, web-config

Here is my code that tries to get a custom configuration object from web.config:

```
LdapConfiguration ldapConfig = (LdapConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ldapConfiguration");
```

When that line of code is ran I get [this error page](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1563210/aspneterror92309.htm).

[Here is screenshot](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1563210/ldapconfigshot.jpg) showing that I have included the reference to the project that contains the configuration object:

I do see the GTCCLdap.dll file in my bin file after I build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the assembly is called `GTCCLdap.dll` but your config is looking for `GTCC.Ldap.dll`.

Unless that was a typo in your question, change your config to this:

```
<section name="ldapConfiguration" type="GTCC.Ldap.LdapConfiguration,GTCCLdap"/>
```